# How to add logged in username after WordPress URL?

Tags: url-rewriting, username

I found a great solution for this issue in this article:
[How to add wordpress username after url?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/300988/how-to-add-wordpress-username-after-url/368226?noredirect=1#comment534861_368226)

```
/*
Plugin Name: My Awesome Button
Description: The shortcode [my-awesome-button] will be replaced with the HTML code for a button for logged-in users and for guests it will be replaced with an empty string (so it will be removed). This will work for posts and pages.
Author: Nikolay Nikolov
Version: 1.0.0
*/

add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_awesome_button_function', 99999999999 );

function my_awesome_button_function( $content ) {
    if ( strpos( $content, '[my-awesome-button]' ) !== false ) {
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
            $button_html = '<a href="https://direktoriku.com/shopping/?user=' . esc_attr( $current_user->user_login ) . '"><button>Click me</button></a>';
            $content = str_replace( '[my-awesome-button]', $button_html, $content );
        } else {
            $content = str_replace( '[my-awesome-button]', '', $content );
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

My only problem, that the button is active only on the homepage and inactive on all of the other pages on the website (for example mydomain.com/documents).

Please be so kind and help me to fix it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: That button will be shown on those pages only where you put the shortcode. `[my-awesome-button]`. Try by adding this shortcode on another page content and check it.

Comment: And you might as well implement this using [add_shortcode()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) not a content_filter if you're going to specify the button in shortcode syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this shortode in this plugin file or you can paste this method to bottom of active theme's `functions.php`. If you are new to WordPress and need a help you can visit [here](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-pasting-snippets-from-the-web-into-wordpress/) for steps to add code in function.

```
add_shortcode( 'my-awesome-button', 'wp_my_awesome_bytton' );
function wp_my_awesome_bytton( $atts ) {
    $button_html = '';
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
            $button_html = '<a href="https://direktoriku.com/shopping/?user=' . esc_attr( $current_user->user_login ) . '"><button>Click me</button></a>';

    }
    return $button_html; 
}
```

// Use this shortcode anywhere in page/post content like this: `[my-awesome-button]` it will replace your shortcode to html code. More information about shortcode [visit here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/).